# Is it safe to trim the torsion bar on a garage door?

Tags: garage-door

The torsion bar on my garage door extends ~6" past the end bearing bracket (picture below).  I would like to trim it by ~3" to place a cabinet on the wall.  Are there any requirements for torsion bar extension beyond the bracket?

[image: torsion bar extension]

The below link seems to indicate centering the torsion bar.  If one side is trimmed should the other side match?
https://diygaragedoor.com/diy-instructions/how-to-install-a-single-torsion-spring-assembly.php

Thanks!

Comment: Is your door slightly undersized? I have never seen the axle of a torsion spring door extend this far out. Some excess is needed to insure that it would not slip out, but I think you could cut off the amount you want to. The ends do not have to have the same length past the bearing. (The axle is not called a torsion bar. A torsion bar is a kind of spring based on twisting *deformation* of a bar. The bar in these garage doors is effectively rigid and merely transmits the torque of the torsion springs).

Comment: As an alternative,  just drill a clearance hole in the side of your cabinet -- and box in the end of the bar inside the cabinet so nothing can jam the bar end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expert/garage door safety paranoiac here.

You know what, I actually feel comfortable with that.

I'd leave several inches beyond the end of the bearing, so if the shaft shifts in the bearing, that's still alright.

No need to trim both sides symmetrically.  Extra length doesn't cost you anything... Unless it does.

Comment: Just watch for the sparks while the metal is cut. Nice dry wood, perhaps some dust, lots of sparks.....

Comment: Keep in mind, with the cabinet on the wall, the bar has to be slid out of the end bearing to replace the spring..